# Zeta Regularized Determinant of Laplacian

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, riemannian-geometry

Can anyone point me to a resource where the zeta regularized determinant of the Laplacian is explicitly computed for simple two dimensional surfaces, say a rectangle or torus or cylinder?

Comment: Just a note - you won't be able to do this for an open cylinder $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}$ because the Laplacian won't have a discrete spectrum.

Comment: Did you ever learn how to compute the regularized determinant of the Laplacian for the rectangle?

Comment: I found it here: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1104271130 (formula 105 on page 256)

Answer (score 2):

Such an explicit computation can be found in Section 4 of [these lectures](http://library.msri.org/books/Book57/files/70kirsten.pdf). They are a part of of the book "A Window into Zeta and Modular Physics'' edited by K. Kirsten and F. L. Williams.

Answer (score 1):

The computation of the $\zeta$-regularization of the determinant of the Laplacian on the torus is done at [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pknzQREI4Us), for example. Akshay Venkatesh used identies in Eisenstein series to resolve the problem, but I am not sure if his computation is entirely correct.